.Net Elastic.Client v8 (not Nest v7) What is the equivalent of the QueryContainer in this new version?
I have a .net maui mobile app. I have a page that I use to filter (I use elasticsearch) events according to many criteria, in particular the type of dance. In the ui, I use chips to represent this filter. There are 6 types and I can select 1 or more. For example, if I select "Latin", it should return Latin dances, if I also select "Modern", it should return Latin AND Modern dances, and if I deselect "Latin", it should return "Modern" dances only.
I saw that the better solution for that is the QueryContainer but according to the new version of NEST (rather a reboot...) Elastic.Client v8, the QueryContainer doesnt exist anymore. Do you guys know the equivalent of that ?
Here is my method who take a collection of string who represent selected dance types and return ids of events. It works with the older version of elasticsearch client :
public async Task<IEnumerable<string?>> SearchEventsByDanceTypeAsync(IEnumerable<string?> selectedDanseTypes)
{

    if (!selectedDanseTypes.Any())
    { 
        return await Task.Run(() => dbService.GetAllEventsFromDb().Select(e => e.Id));
    }

    var searchResponse = await _client.SearchAsync<EventIndex>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(selectedDanseTypes.Select(danceType => new QueryContainer(new MatchQuery
                {
                    Field = Infer.Field<EventIndex>(f => f.DanceType),
                    Query = danceType
                })))))
    );

    var eventIds = searchResponse.Documents.Select(e => e.Id).ToArray();
    return eventIds;
}

I saw that there is a "QueryDescriptor" object in this new version maybe its the solution.
